# Kanthal winding protection tube?

Tags: heating-systems

I have a kanthal wire wound around a D=4mm and L=15mm standard pneumatic tube to solve the problem of freezing one of the tube ports that is exposed to the outer environment (and hence can be clogged with ice).

How to protect the kanthal winding?

For rigid design, see https://www.teknotherm.com.tr/Content/Theme/Site/Files/Editor/images/p_kanthal-isitma-telleri.jpg that reminds me of ferrite Beads https://v3.airspy.us/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/X-5mm-Ferrite.jpg.

But the protection should be soft (to be able to bend slightly around the pneumatic tube) so I cannot use plaster of paris and sand to fix the winding in.
What kind of material would you suggest to make a soft tube (4mm inner diameter, 5-7mm outer diameter) filled with this material that holds wound kanthal wire in? Or how would you solve this problem otherwise?